# Can Jprofile connect to JVM running in docker

Tags: docker, jvm, jprofiler

I'm new to JProfiler. I came into a problem recently. My Java app is running in docker which means the JVM is runnning in docker. But my jprofile is installed in the host machine. I know the jprofiler must connect to a JVM. So, is there anyway that the jprofiler can connect to jvm running in docker?

Comment: @PatrickAleman that would be a good answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remote profilling java application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7571247/remote-profilling-java-application)

Comment: But the answer of that question is not the same thing I asked

Comment: remote just means a subset of anything you can also do locally or with containers, therefore it is applicable here.

Answer (score 5):

It is similar as connects JProfiler to a remote JVM, you just need to have the JProfiler agent ready inside your container and expose the port.

This post has a step by step guide
http://geekspearls.blogspot.com.au/2016/08/configure-jprofiler-92-to-profiling.html

Comment: I found I had to map the port after following the guide. docker run -p 8849:8849 imageName

Answer (score 4):

You can use this dockerfile; https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/gingerbeard/java8-jprofiler/dockerfile/

```
FROM dockerfile/java:oracle-java8
MAINTAINER gingerbeard <kulishovt@gmail.com>

RUN wget http://download-aws.ej-technologies.com/jprofiler/jprofiler_linux_8_1_2.tar.gz -P /tmp/ &&\
 tar -xzf /tmp/jprofiler_linux_8_1_2.tar.gz -C /usr/local &&\
 rm /tmp/jprofiler_linux_8_1_2.tar.gz

ENV JPAGENT_PATH="-agentpath:/usr/local/jprofiler8/bin/linux-x64/libjprofilerti.so=nowait"
EXPOSE 8849

CMD ["bash"]
```

make sure to check the ports.

Answer (score 0):

The JProfiler GUI connects to the profiling agent that is loaded in the profiled JVM through a TCP socket.

This is always the case, also if the profiled JVM and the JProfiler GUI are running on the same machine.

Invoking "Session->Integration wizards->New remote integration" will give you the instructions to set this up manually.

Comment: I've figured it out. The right way is install jprofiler inside the container with your java app. Start the jprofiler using "docker exec" in your host machine. Then u can monitor your container in your local machine.